# Use javascript to open and parse a file without server

Tags: javascript, csv

Ok, I have a webpage that will run locally, every hour it needs to read a csv "output.csv" and put its contents into a table.  The output.csv is generated from a local program automatically.  The goal being an internal status board.

The only thing I can't seem to figure out is, without a server or xmlrequst how do I load a plaintext into javascript?  (the rest of it should be easy)

This is the code that I've tried:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(event) {
    var contents = event.target.result;
    console.log("File contents: " + contents);
};

reader.onerror = function(event) {
    console.error("File could not be read! Code " + event.target.error.code);
};

reader.readAsText("output.csv");
```

EDIT:

I've read that using this option "--allow-file-access-from-files" will override the settings and allow me to read local files from chrome.  I'm sure there is a way.

Comment: Why you don't want to use AJAX request?

Comment: Can you use AJAX without a server and grabbing a local file, I thought not.  If you could provide an example, maybe using jsfiddle, in the answer section, I'll mark it

Comment: [use File or Blob objects to specify the file or data to read.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

Comment: You cannot instantiate `FileReader` object directly (`var reader = new FileReader())`. `FileReader` objects are obtained indirectly: as a result of a user selecting or from a drag and drop operation

Comment: @hindmost why cannot instantiate `FileReader`? `var reader = new FileReader()` work ok

Comment: @triunenature try see [Selecting_files_using_drag_and_drop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Selecting_files_using_drag_and_drop)

Comment: @Grundy Offcourse can instantiate it. But it won't work as you expected

Comment: @hindmost why do you think so? :-) just pass to it file or blob and all work as expected

Comment: @Grundy drag and drop wont work, since this process is entirely automated.  No user will be dragging or dropping, the webpage / js need to do the actions completely by themselfs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found an answer!

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.get("output.csv", function( my_var ) {
        alert(my_var)
    });

});
```

**Chrome:**
"chrome.exe --user-data-dir=c:\temp --allow-file-access-from-files --incognito """ & currentDirectory & "index.html"""

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you are running JavaScript, that is running in the browser and for security reasons it cannot access any file from your computer. So if you are willing to stick with JavaScript just start a server (e.g. [SimpleHttpServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) or [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/)) which will supply the file to your code.

Otherwise you will need to ask the user explicitly to "upload" your `csv` to the webpage - even though it is offline and living in his browser.

Comment: I can't start a server, as the machine is locked down.  The user is me, but this thing needs to be done completely automated.  It's a full screen application running on a large screen.  It will be running for months at a time without me even touching it.

Comment: The "Security Reasons" can and are disbled, "--allow-file-access-from-files", I have used this flag.  Now with the security gone, how do I load the file?